# Jenkins grails error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: geb.transform.AttributeAccessingMetaClassRegisteringTransformation

Tags: grails, jenkins

I trying to run geb and spock tests on Jenkins with grails 2.3.4 but I get error

```
Error |
Error executing script TestApp: startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class 
geb.transform.AttributeAccessingMetaClassRegisteringTransformation specified at 
jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/gebish/geb-ast/0.12.0/geb-ast-0.12.0.jar!/
META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  
because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
geb.transform.AttributeAccessingMetaClassRegisteringTransformation

Could not instantiate global transform class 
geb.transform.implicitassertions.ImplicitAssertionsTransformation specified at 
jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/gebish/geb-implicit-assertions/0.12.0/
geb-implicit-assertions-0.12.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.
ASTTransformation because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
geb.transform.implicitassertions.ImplicitAssertionsTransformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I figure out my Jenkins was using java 6 and grails 2.3.4. When I update java version from 6 to 7 and grails from 2.3.4 to 2.4.5 version all was worked correctly.